TabView indicator disappears
TabView {
    ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
        Image(image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
}
.frame(height: 320)
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
.tabViewStyle(.page)

In this code, when I use .scaledToFit(), indicator on image disappears.
And using .scaledToFill() shows indicator.
Why do these two modifiers work differently?
If I don't use any modifier in this code, the indicator still appears on the image.

They are different. What is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

This problem may be because the page indicators are always white, with different degrees of opacity. These dots can only be seen if the background is not white.
If you are testing with wide images on a tall display, images that are scaled-to-fit will have some blank space above and below them. Therefore, if you are running in light mode, the page indicators will probably disappear into the white background.
Try setting a non-white background behind the images, or just switch to dark mode to confirm that the indicators are actually there:


In the example here, you will also notice that the image does not have rounded corners, even though you have applied a RoundedRectangle clip shape. This is because, the frame height is being fixed to 320, so the rounded corners are happening in a blank part of the frame.
If you want an image that is scaled-to-fit to have rounded corners, try moving the clipShape modifier to the image inside the ForEach:
ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
    Image(image)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)) // <- HERE
}


